# website unreachable from one server, ping ok, and website ok from others servers

Tags: http, networking

my websites daneel.net et plcoder.net are hosted on a french hosting services provider, and are unreachable from a canadian server since august 1st 22h35 GMT+1.

Ping work well, and IP is good.

> **(~)$ ping www.daneel.net**
>   PING pessac.nexen.net (217.174.203.6):
>   56 data bytes 64 bytes from
>   217.174.203.6: icmp_seq=0 ttl=48 time=97.602 ms

SSH work well

> **(~)$ telnet**
>   www.daneel.net 22 Trying
>   217.174.203.6... Connected to www.daneel.net. Escape character is
>   '^]'. SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_3.8.1p1
>   Debian-8.sarge.6

and FTP too, but not HTTP

> **(~)$ wget daneel.net**
>   --2010-08-02 10:30:35--  http://daneel.net/ Resolving
>   daneel.net... 217.174.203.6 Connecting
>   to daneel.net|217.174.203.6|:80...
>   failed: Connection timed out.
>   Retrying.

From my canadian server others french web sites are reachable, even in the network of my french provider.

How can I understand where is the problem? One the french server or on the canadian one? On the french one I only have ftp and http access, one the canadian I have a ssh shell.
It is not the first time my websites are unreachables from the canadian server, but it had run for months without problem.

thanks for your help
Regards
Cédric Girard

ps : A traceroute

> ****(~)$ /usr/sbin/traceroute daneel.net****
>   traceroute to daneel.net (217.174.203.6), 64 hops max, 40 byte packets
>     1  gate221b.csoft.net (205.205.221.253)  4.868 ms  0.619 ms  0.831 ms
>     2  66.48.31.92 (66.48.31.92)  1.87 ms  1.935 ms  1.267 ms
>     3  909.GigabitEthernet5-0.GW1.MTL2.ALTER.NET (205.205.220.233)  1.962 ms  0.868 ms  0.831 ms
>     4  105.at-6-0-0.XR1.MTL1.ALTER.NET (152.63.130.66)  1.377 ms  1.280 ms   1.265 ms
>     5  0.so-0-0-0.XT1.MTL1.ALTER.NET (152.63.133.45)  1.230 ms  1.230 ms 1.272 ms
>     6  0.so-1-0-1.XL3.NYC4.ALTER.NET (152.63.0.213)  8.979 ms  8.842 ms 9.19 ms
>     7  0.ae3.BR2.NYC4.ALTER.NET (152.63.3.110)  9.713 ms  8.839 ms  33.897 ms
>     8  * 204.255.168.174 (204.255.168.174)  18.60 ms  13.49 ms
>     9  if-14-0-0-1260.core2.NTO-NewYork.as6453.net (209.58.26.65)  9.559 ms if-12-0-0-13.core2.NTO-NewYork.as6453.net (216.6.97.45)  9.116 ms if-13-0-0-475.core2.NTO-NewYork.as6453.net (216.6.97.89)  9.255 ms
>   10  if-5-0.mcore4.MTT-Montreal.as6453.net (216.6.115.21)  17.413 ms 16.558 ms  16.536 ms
>   11  if-3-0.mcore3.MTT-Montreal.as6453.net (216.6.114.1)  26.93 ms 17.191 ms  23.205 ms
>   12  if-5-0-0-1611.core1.PV1-Paris.as6453.net (216.6.114.50)  100.247 ms   100.489 ms  100.875 ms
>   13  if-6-781.har1.PV0-Paris.as6453.net (195.219.215.62)  100.827 ms 100.817 ms  100.842 ms
>   14  Vlan1141.icore1.PG1-Paris.as6453.net (195.219.224.86)  99.71 ms * 98.996 ms
>   15  if-13-0-0-883.core1.PV1-Paris.as6453.net (80.231.73.10)  103.994 ms   103.963 ms  103.640 ms
>   16  cruet.nexen.net (89.31.144.8)  97.288 ms  101.662 ms  96.725 ms
>   17  pessac.nexen.net (217.174.203.6)  97.844 ms  97.422 ms  97.795 ms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, ask to the providers is the good answer, and one of them admit to have blocked the other's IP.

Answer (score 2):

If you have root access you could try the tcp traceroute option if available
e.g. under linux it would be:

```
traceroute -M tcp -p 80 www.somedomain.com
```

That will try to connect via port 80 over tcp.
Hopefully you will be able to identify where the problem is then.